# Is it possible to create a base Solr schema?

Tags: xml, inheritance, solr, schema

We have a number of Solr schema.xml files that are all nearly identical. It would be great if we could pull out the common parts and put them in a base schema that we then override in custom schema files.

Looking at my schema files, about 1/7th of each file is custom and the rest is boilerplate that could be pulled out and centralized.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to do this is solr itself then I don't think that's possible.

Alternatively what you could do is have one copy of your base schema that you use every time you create a new core/collection and then use the schema api to make whatever changes you need. This will however require you to write some code or make some api calls at the least.

Comment: So I guess this approach means that we have a base and then encode our customizations in Python calls to the Schema API. We only create cores programmatically, so this could work. I don't love how separate the schema.xml files are from the Python code, but it could be the best/only solution.

Comment: One more idea that comes to mind is to use dynamic fields. You could have your base schema as explicitly defined fields and the other different fields as a host of dynamic fields. That would entail that you have advanced knowledge of all the possible fields that could crop up so that you can create the dynamic fields accordingly but it would also mean that you only need just 1 schema throughout.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but we expose the field names to users, so they can do queries like `org:foo`. If we use dynamic fields, then our field names have to change.

Comment: I don't know how well this will sit with your use case, but you could have certain not catch-all but catch-some fields that are copied from your dynamic fields that you expose to the users for query purposes, maybe based on a certain grouping of fields depending on their use.

Answer (score 0):

TYPO3 does it using general XML *x:include*. Here is [the English example](https://github.com/TYPO3-Solr/ext-solr/blob/master/Resources/Solr/typo3cores/conf/english/schema.xml) on GitHub, and they have a lot more there.

This probably will not play well with the managed schema, as it will regenerate a full-schema on first read.

Alternatively, as Binoy wrote, bootstrap schema from common source and then use [Schema API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API) to apply the changes.